# Trying to Optimize PostgreSQL Nested WHERE IN

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have a Postgres (9.1) customer database similar to:

```
customers.id
customers.lastname
customers.firstname

invoices.id
invoices.customerid
invoices.total

invoicelines.id
invoicelines.invoiceid
invoicelines.itemcode
invoicelines.price
```

I built a search which lists all customers who have purchased a certain item (say 'abc').

```
Select * from customers WHERE customers.id IN
    (Select invoices.customerid FROM invoices WHERE invoices.id IN
        (Select invoicelines.invoiceid FROM invoicelines WHERE
        invoicelines.itemcode = 'abc')
    )
```

The search works fine and brings up the correct customers but takes about 10 seconds or so on a database of 2 million invoices and 2 million line items.

I was wondering if there was another approach that could trim that down a bit.

Comment: Have you tried a join instead?  `Select * from customers inner join  invoices on invoices.customerid = customers.id inner join inoicelines.invoiceid = invoices.invoiceid where invoicelines.itemcode = 'abc'`

Comment: Read: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info then [**Edit your question**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35700292/edit) and add the missing information

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to use `EXISTS`:

```
Select * 
from customers 
WHERE EXISTS (
   Select invoices.customerid 
   FROM invoices 
   JOIN invoicelines
      ON invoicelines.invoiceid = invoices.id AND
         invoicelines.itemcode = 'abc' AND
         customers.id = invoices.customerid)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might switch to using `exists` instead.  I suspect that this might work well:

```
Select c.*
from customers c 
where exists (Select 1
              from invoices i join
                   invoicelines il
                   on i.id = il.invoiceid and il.itemcode = 'abc'
              where c.id = i.customerid
             );
```

For this, you want to be sure you have the right indexes:  `invoices(customerid, id)` and `invoicelines(invoiceid, itemcode)`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want all of the rows and columns in `customer` where the `itemcode` for that customer's item is `'abc`'? If you join on the `customerid` then you can find all of the customer information for those items. If you have duplicates within that list you can use `DISTINCT` which will only give you one entry per `customerID`.

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT [List of customer columns] 
FROM 
    customers 
INNER JOIN 
    invoicelines 
ON 
    customers.customerid = invoicelines.customerid
AND
    invoicelines.itemcode = 'abc'
```